# how to new project and deploy it to a virtual directory of an existing site?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have already Existing project. I have created new project . I want to   new project and deploy it to a virtual directory of an existing site.  I want to install MVC forum NuGet theme my  Existing project. i am following this way

1. Create a new project and deploy it to a virtual directory of an existing site.
2. Having 2 separate projects doesn't mean they can't run on the same site.  Unless you have a specific reason for wanting it to run in an existing project (like view injection/route hijacking).
3. If so... It's hacky (really hacky) but you can create a new C# project in a subfolder of an existing C# project.  Create a new solution in that sub folder to.  Load the subfolder solution by itself and add the sub folder C# project to it. Add MVC Forum to it and save.  Then close that solution and open the parent solution and click show all files and add the subfolder to the project while excluding the .sln and .csproj \bin \obj etc.

So structure would look like this,

Existing Project:

- MVCForumSubFolder

  - MVCForum.sln //exclude
  - MVCForum.csproj //exclude
  - Views //include
  - etc

On another note, I'm going to dive into building a NuGet package generator for MVCForum soon and if possible I'll have it prompt to do a root add or a subfolder add (subfolder assuming virtual directory configuration).

how can do this  new project deploy it to a virtual directory of an Existing Site ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Azure for deployment. Then look the following link for how to create a virtual directory in windows azure.

http://blog.logiticks.com/virtual-directory-in-azure-website/

Comment: i want am deploy local IIS